# How to use PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer at Java SE project

Tags: java, spring, properties

I am have spring configuration below to use access propeties in a file from java Classess.
There are many ways for JavaEE project like follow:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.service.pack" />
    <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="appProperties"/>
```

I am able to use above method in java SE project so tried PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer classes  but at this time  applicationProperties beans is not seen from PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer  class so propertiesMap is null.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a simple way of accecing property from class file like javaee projects

```
<bean id="applicationProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:app.properties"/>
</bean>



@Component
public class PropertiesUtil extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {
   private static Map<String, String> propertiesMap;

   @Override
   protected void processProperties(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory,
             Properties props) throws BeansException {
        super.processProperties(beanFactory, props);

        propertiesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (Object key : props.keySet()) {
            String keyStr = key.toString();
            propertiesMap.put(keyStr, parseStringValue(props.getProperty(keyStr),
                props, new HashSet()));
        }
    }

    public static String getProperty(String name) {
        return (String) propertiesMap.get(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: And why would it be different in a Jave SE project... There isn't a difference...

Comment: when processProperties( method is invoked, Properties props parameters is null. why?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you're trying to do but in your sample project above, `PropertiesUtil` extends from `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` but your XML configuration refers to `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and not your sub-class. So if that's all you have, your class is not even invoked.

I tried that locally with the following config and it worked:

```
<bean id="applicationProperties" class="com.foo.yourpackage.PropertiesUtil">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:app.properties"/>
</bean>
```

Now, I understand you're trying to access to the properties in your code.The `Environment` abstraction has all that you need, check [this blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/) and the [javadoc of Environment](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) for more details.